# Classifying event data

Tags: machine-learning, classification, cluster-analysis

I'm getting started with machine learning and analytics, and my approach is to dive right in with data and learn methods/tools as I need them.

I have a set of event data, logging people's movement in/out of a room using via RFID chips with unique ids so that I have a timestamp of when a chip enters a room and when it leaves.  I want to classify the chip ids based on their movements in and out of the room.

For instance,

- A chip that leaves and comes back regularly could belong to someone who works in that room.
- A chip that enters and stays for a long time may belong to electronic equipment which is moved around.
- A chip that comes and leaves a short while later, with few or only one set of entrances/exits could be a visitor.
- A chip that spends minimal time in the room and does not visit often could just be someone walking through.

Those are my four main categories.

So far, I have tried k-means clustering.  For each chip, I compute some parameters that could indicate a particular category: average time spent in room, number of days seen in a week, total time spent in a room, and average number of entrances/exits per day.

With this, I have seen some reasonable results, but depending on what parameters I use results vary drastically.  Looking at chip parameters I generate on plot, there's a lot of variation in the classification.  I do not have any good training data, which is why I tried a classification method first.

I'm mainly looking for some advice on what might be better algorithms or techniques to use, or even if my approach is way off.  I can provide code or dummy data if needed, but I'm really just looking for a good direction.

Comment: Could you provide examples of the features you're using? I suspect feature engineering is the area you're likely to overlook that would have the most immediate impact on what comes out of the method.

Comment: You might want to use supervised methods for this instead of clustering. In particularly k-means is really just a crude heuristic, and I'm not at all surprised it doesn't work reliably.

Comment: Posting a sample of your data would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a fun problem to work on ! Here are just a couple of general suggestions that might give you some good ideas.

First, it would be useful if you were able to identify some sort of goal that you're trying to achieve by modeling this data. It could be that you'd like to identify intruders, or learn how many different classes of RFID badge there are (you listed four in your question, but what if there are really five or ten ?), or some other task entirely. You might need different data depending on the task that you identify, but it would be useful because then you could have a gauge of whether what you're trying is actually working. Hope that makes sense.

Second, if you're using k-means (or any clustering algorithm, really) to model your data in an unsupervised manner, it's a good idea to normalize the features of your data. Suppose you had just two features -- one that indicates the hour of last entrance into a room, and another that indicates the total number of entrances in a month. The values of the first feature will be in the range [0, 24) while the second could range from 0 up to 1000 (say). Then, when you're computing the distance between data points, the second feature might dominate the distance computation just because the numeric values are larger. For starters, try subtracting the mean from each feature and then dividing by the standard deviation. This will hopefully make your feature clusters more stable, if nothing else.